# Can I set a value of one variable based on another declaratively?

Tags: angularjs

Lets say on my scope, I have the boolean:

```
$scope.isChecked = true;
$scope.selected = false;
```

and in my html I have

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="isChecked" ng-show="selected = isChecked"/>
```

Is the code in ng-show valid?  Can I update the selected variable based on isChecked?  In this case selected would be set to true.

ng-show wasn't the best directive to use here? Is there a directive that will update the value of selected if isChecked is updated?

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-hover" ng-show="activeTab=='inbox'">
     <tbody>
       <tr ng-repeat="email in emails">
            <td>
             <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="master" 
                                    ng-model="email.isChecked" 
                                    ng-change="selected = email.isChecked"/>
           </td>
</tr>
</table>

(function () {

var app = window.angular.module("mail", []);

app.controller("emailController", ["$scope", "emailService", function emailController($scope, emailService) {


    $scope.selected = false;

    $scope.getEmails = function () {
        emailService.getEmails().then(function (data) {
            $scope.emails = data;
        });
    };
```

After getEmails is called, $scope.emails[0].email, for example, has an isChecked property and if any emails are checked, I want to set the $scope.selected to true, but if all are no checked, then I want to set $scope.selected to false.  I wonder if doing a loop is the way to go, but if I have tons of emails, that might take a while

Comment: Wouldn't your checkbox vanish on deselection? And ofcourse you can abuse `ng-show` to update another scope variable.. and it is valid :)

Comment: @PSL - true, lol, I wasn't sure if it could actually be done anyways.  I guess another way to rephrase it is, can I update selected using another directive besides ng-show?

Comment: what do you mean by another directive, you have some custom ones? Well you could use `ng-change`. Are you inside an ng-repeat by the way?

Comment: @PSL - I updated the post with more info.

Answer (score 0):

As you have written the code

```
ng-show="selected = isChecked"
```

it will obviously be execute;
This will be just like

```
$scope.selected = $scope.isChecked
```

In you specific case,I would suggest that
perform loop only if `isChecked` is `false`.

like:

```
ng-change="checkedChanged(email.isChecked)"

$scope.checkedChanged = function(chk) {
    if(chk) {
      $scope.selected = true;
    } else {
      var checkedFlag=false;
      //loop here

      $scope.selected = checkedFlag;
    }
```

}

Comment: I guess ng-show wasn't the best directive to use here.  Is it possible to update selected using another directive?

Comment: you can use `watch` `$scope.$watch('isChecked', function() { $scope.selected = $scope.isChecked});`

Comment: I tried   `$scope.$watch('isChecked', function () {
            $scope.emailIsSelected = $scope.isChecked;
            console.log($scope.isChecked);
            console.log($scope.emailIsSelected);
        });`, but it is not updating $scope.emailIsSelected.  When I load the page, both variables are undefined.  Do I need to do anything else besides watch?

Comment: My variables are defined as true false, but when I check the console, it says they are undefined.

Comment: strange result. have you tried with `$scope.isChecked = true`. And checked in html that it is checking the checked box or not with that code?